# facebook api - reading user's stream (home) through facebook api and paging through it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to read a user's stream using the facebook graph api. the call is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=xxxxx&since=yyyyy
```

I am getting a response but there are a few problems:

1. Why in the response are some of the posts missing? (whether i am using the parameter "since" or not) I.E. the result I get as a response is not identical to the stream I see as a facebbok user (many posts are missing)
2. It seems that even if I use the "since" parameter, many of the posts returned are out of the time scope. Any ideas why? I would like to do paging according to specific time periods but it seems facebook api is not working as expected.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because of individual user's privacy settings.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but: 
1. the user is myself and the token is for myself, yet the stream is different.
2. it doesnt seem there is a pattern in the missing posts from the stream..